# Identification of a seed with unknown origin

Tags: identification, seeds

I have a seed that I would like to identify. I got this from a friend who does not know anything about the origin, so I have tried my favorite search engine with all kinds of keywords, looked up a few seed databases, but I was not successful so far. I hope you can help me!

EDIT: I am from Germany, but I am not sure if the seed is from here.

[image: seed]

Comment: what area are you located?  that may help people...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found this article about [sea beans](https://daniellesdives.wordpress.com/2012/06/18/what-the-heck-is-a-sea-bean/), which look just like my seed.